# How to Remove part of a String and Convert a Number

Tags: r

I'm pretty brand new to R and having an issue with a data frame.

So i have a dataframe dataf that looks like this:

```
#         PlayerName           playerValue
#5     Tammy Abraham          10,00 Mill. €  
#6     Abdul Rahman Baba      8,00 Mill. €  
#7     Mario Pasalic          8,00 Mill. €  
#8     Lewis Baker            5,50 Mill. €  
#9     Ola Aina               4,00 Mill. €  
#10    Jamal Blackman         500 Th. €
```

Then I use the line:

```
dataf$playerValue <- gsub(",", ".", gsub("[[:space:]].*", "", dataf$PlayerValue))
```

The output of this is:

```
#         PlayerName           playerValue        playerValue
#5     Tammy Abraham          10,00 Mill. €           10
#6     Abdul Rahman Baba      8,00 Mill. €            8
#7     Mario Pasalic          8,00 Mill. €            8
#8     Lewis Baker            5,50 Mill. €            5.5
#9     Ola Aina               4,00 Mill. €            4
#10    Jamal Blackman         500 Th. €               500
```

Is there anyway to make the final value from 500 to .5? Because obviously 500 thousand is smaller than 4 million, but here the int 500 is going to be larger than 4.

Also, how do I just exclude the original PlayerValue column? When I run my code it prints out the column twice, once with the String at the end and the converted column too.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: As far as the printing twice goes, note that `playerValue` isn't the same as `PlayerValue`. You have a typo. As far as you other question, I don't see any shortcut to using `ifelse()` with a condition that checks for `"Th"`, but maybe someone with more regular expression expertise than I has a slicker approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea where it extracts the values from each string and if the word `Mill` is not found in the string, it divides by 1000, i.e.

Assume the data frame,

```
 playerName         playerValue
1  Tammy Abraham    10,00 Mill. €
2 Jamal Blackman    500 Th. €
```

then,

```
v1 <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', gsub(',.*', '', df$playerValue)))
v1[!grepl('Mill', df$playerValue)] <- v1[!grepl('Mill', df$playerValue)] / 1000
v1
#[1] 10.0  0.5
```

[Here is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013217/convert-from-billion-to-million-and-vice-versa) although not exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to separate millions/thousands when extracting the numbers.

```
# dummy data
dataf <- data.frame(playerValue = c("500 Th. € ","4,00 Mill. € "))
# Extract with regex
mils <- 10^3 * as.numeric(gsub("^(\\d+?)\\,(\\d+?)\\s.*|^(\\d+?)\\s.*", "\\1", 
                               dataf$playerValue, perl = TRUE))
thsd <- as.numeric(gsub("^(\\d+?)\\,(\\d+?)\\s.*|^(\\d+?)\\s.*", "\\2\\3", 
                   dataf$playerValue, perl = TRUE))
# Final result
rowSums(cbind(mils, thsd), na.rm = TRUE)
# returns
[1]  500 4000
```

Comment: I think you will find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543627/extracting-numbers-from-vectors-of-strings

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple answer using **strsplit** and **ifelse**.

```
# Dummy data
df <- data.frame(playerValue = c("500 Th. € ","4,00 Mill. € "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Splitting number and scale into two columns
splits <- strsplit(df$playerValue, split = " ")
splits <- do.call(rbind, splits)

# Replacing commas
splits[,1] <- gsub(",", ".", splits[,1])

# Adding to dataframe
df$value <- as.numeric(splits[,1])
df$scale <- splits[,2]

# Calculating new values
df$new_value <- ifelse(df$scale == "Th.", df$value/1000, df$value)
```