# How to Find, Replace, and Multiply in a table

Tags: r

I have a data table from REGIS that includes in random columns, numeric amounts that are summarized by "$1.11 M"(as an example) instead of 1,110,000.00 as a number. In these random columns, it could either show as a "M" or "B" or "K" ( for Millions, Billions, or Thousands).

I am trying to figure out a code that will find and remove the "$" and "M", then multiply the numeric number by 1,000,000 (or whatever the the dollar amount should be).

I have tried using `lapply`, `if_else`, `Gsub`... but I can't figure out how to only make these changes to the cells that have the characters "$" and "M" (or "B"," K")

So far i have:

```
df1$1<-sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]", list(K = "*1000", M = "*1e6", B = "*1e9"), 
    sub("$", "",df1$1, fixed = TRUE)), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
```

The problem is that I am looking for a way to make this code cover all of my columns at once.. just not a specific column.

I expect to change (for example) "$1.65 K" to be 1,650.00 or "3.96 M" to 3,960,000.00

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013217/convert-from-billion-to-million-and-vice-versa) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `gsubfn` to replace the 'M', 'K' values with a multiplier string by passing a key/val `list`, then `eval`uate the string and change it to custom format with `dollar_format` from `scales`

```
library(gsubfn)
library(scales)
out <- sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]", list(K = "*1000", M = "*1e6"), 
    sub("$", "", str1, fixed = TRUE)), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
dollar_format()(out)
#[1] "$1,650"     "$3,960,000"
```

---

If we need to change for all the columns

```
df1[] <-lapply(df1, function(x)  dollar_format()(sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]",
        list(K = "*1000", M = "*1e6", B = "*1e9"), 
    sub("$", "", x, fixed = TRUE)), function(y) eval(parse(text = y)))))
```

#### Update

OP came up with some more patterns.  For that, we can do

```
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) {
     i1 <- grepl("[KMB]", x) # create index to change only those have KMB 
     x[i1] <- dollar_format()(
       sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]", list(K = "*1000", M = "*1e6", B = "*1e9"),
          sub("$", "", x[i1], fixed = TRUE)),
        function(y) eval(parse(text = y))))
      x
     })
df2
#        col1       col2
#1     $1,650     $1,650
#2 $3,960,000 $3,960,000
#3    $-1,650    $-1,650
#4       -950       -950
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("$1.65 K" ,  "3.96 M")
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = str1, col2 = str1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str2 <- c("$1.65 K" ,  "3.96 M", "-$1.65 K", "-950")
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = str2, col2 = str2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: If the table I am using is called "DF", where would that fit into the script you provided? Sorry i am pretty new to R.

Comment: Am i able to use this code when dealing with a data table instead of a string of values?

Comment: @J.Shields  Yes you can use `DF$columnname`

Comment: First off, the code works great! Is there a way I can get it to check all of my columns at once? the table has 374 columns.. all of which could have the formatting that I am trying to change.

Comment: @J.Shields  Yes, if it is a data.frame `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) ...)`

Comment: Adding your above comment to the full code... is this correct?df1[]<-lapply(df1, function(x) sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]", list(K = "*1000", M = "*1e6", B = "*1e9"), 
+                             sub("$", "", test_main_df, fixed = TRUE)), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))

Comment: I think the `sub("$","", x, fixed = TRUE)` where 'x' is the anonymous function call for the column element.  In the second `function(x)`, it is for the `sapply` loop.  I would name it as `y` instead of 'x' to avoid confusion

Comment: So this is what should work? I tried running and it doesn't look to be working..

df1[]<-lapply(df1, function(x) sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]", list(K = "*1000", M = "*1e6", B = "*1e9"),  sub("$", "", df1, fixed = TRUE)), function(y) eval(parse(text = y))))

Comment: @J.Shields  In the `sub` call, you were using the whole data 'df1', instead of 'x'.  Try `lapply(df1, function(x)  dollar_format()(sapply(gsubfn("[A-Z]", list(K = "*1000", M = "*1e6", B = "*1e9"), sub("$", "", x, fixed = TRUE)), function(y) eval(parse(text = y)))))`

Comment: Thanks so much! this is great. The (hopefully) last issue that i have is that there are negative numbers in the table, so when i run the script i get this error:
`Error in parse(text = y) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: -
   ^ `
Is there a way it can ignore the "-"?

Comment: @J.Shields  Can you show an example.  Is it like `-$1.65 K"` if you want to ignore, then do `{i1 <- !grepl("^-", x); x1 <- x[i1];` and then update the elements that don't have the `-`

Comment: So I found instances where there are numbers like "-$1.65 k" that I would like changed to "-1,650.00". But at the same time I found amounts that are "-950", and i would like that to stay the way it is. With your code above, where would i enter that into the script? Do i need a closing "}" added to it as well?