# How to convert all the values to billion in dataframe?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to convert all the values to billion in dataframe and then calculate its mean.

```
DF1 <- data.frame("Brand"=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),"Revenue"=c("$50.21 M","$20.31 B","$50.23 M","$41.45 B","$29.10 M","$32.21 M"))
show(DF1)

temp<-as.numeric(gsub("^[[:punct:]]", "",DF1$Revenue))
temp

temp_num<- as.numeric(as.character(DF1$Revenue))
```

> Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Do you think you can convert character to numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013217/convert-from-billion-to-million-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

An option is to extract the numeric part with `parse_number`, convert the values to `billion` by dividing the values that have "M" suffix with 1000 and get the `mean` of the 'Revenue` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DF1 %>% 
  mutate(Revenue = readr::parse_number(as.character(Revenue)) * 
          c(1, 1/1e3)[str_detect(Revenue, "M") + 1]) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Revenue))
```

Answer (score 1):

After your `gsub()`, the column could be split with `strsplit()`. Then we can convert the one column into a factor and translate `"M"` and `"B"` into numerical labels. Now we coerce to numeric,  calculate the products, and finally may easily calculate the mean divided by 1e9 (using American billions).

```
s <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(gsub("^[[:punct:]]", "", DF1$Revenue), " "))
s[, 2] <- factor(s[, 2], labels=c("1e9", "1e6"))
res <- mean(apply(s, 1, function(x) prod(as.numeric(as.character(x)))))/1e9
# [1] 10.32029
```

For a final output we may use `formatC`.

```
formatC(res, format="f", big.mark=",", digits=2)
# [1] "10.32"
```