# Finding letters mixed with numbers?

Tags: r

So I'm working with a dataset that has values of 16M instead of 16,000,000. How do I find the other currency denotations? This dataset is massive, so it's not feasible to manually check. Thank you!

Below are the first 250 samples. The structure of the dataset is as follows:
country, year, GDP($), and classification of the data(GDP).

```
structure(list(country = c("Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", "Aruba", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan"), year = c("1799", "1800", "1801", "1802", "1803", 
"1804", "1805", "1806", "1807", "1808", "1809", "1810", "1811", 
"1812", "1813", "1814", "1815", "1816", "1817", "1818", "1819", 
"1820", "1821", "1822", "1823", "1824", "1825", "1826", "1827", 
"1828", "1829", "1830", "1831", "1832", "1833", "1834", "1835", 
"1836", "1837", "1838", "1839", "1840", "1841", "1842", "1843", 
"1844", "1845", "1846", "1847", "1848", "1849", "1850", "1851", 
"1852", "1853", "1854", "1855", "1856", "1857", "1858", "1859", 
"1860", "1861", "1862", "1863", "1864", "1865", "1866", "1867", 
"1868", "1869", "1870", "1871", "1872", "1873", "1874", "1875", 
"1876", "1877", "1878", "1879", "1880", "1881", "1882", "1883", 
"1884", "1885", "1886", "1887", "1888", "1889", "1890", "1891", 
"1892", "1893", "1894", "1895", "1896", "1897", "1898", "1899", 
"1900", "1901", "1902", "1903", "1904", "1905", "1906", "1907", 
"1908", "1909", "1910", "1911", "1912", "1913", "1914", "1915", 
"1916", "1917", "1918", "1919", "1920", "1921", "1922", "1923", 
"1924", "1925", "1926", "1927", "1928", "1929", "1930", "1931", 
"1932", "1933", "1934", "1935", "1936", "1937", "1938", "1939", 
"1940", "1941", "1942", "1943", "1944", "1945", "1946", "1947", 
"1948", "1949", "1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955", 
"1956", "1957", "1958", "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", 
"1964", "1965", "1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", 
"1972", "1973", "1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", 
"1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", 
"1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", 
"1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", 
"2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "1799", "1800", "1801", "1802", "1803", "1804", "1805", 
"1806", "1807", "1808", "1809", "1810", "1811", "1812", "1813", 
"1814", "1815", "1816", "1817", "1818", "1819", "1820", "1821", 
"1822", "1823", "1824", "1825", "1826", "1827", "1828", "1829", 
"1830", "1831", "1832", "1833", "1834"), value = c("16.9M", "16.9M", 
"16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", 
"16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", 
"16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "16.9M", "17.1M", "17.3M", 
"17.5M", "17.7M", "17.9M", "18.1M", "18.4M", "18.6M", "18.8M", 
"19M", "19.3M", "19.5M", "19.7M", "19.9M", "20.2M", "20.4M", 
"20.7M", "20.9M", "21.2M", "21.4M", "21.7M", "21.9M", "22.2M", 
"22.4M", "22.7M", "23M", "23.3M", "23.5M", "23.8M", "24.1M", 
"24.4M", "24.7M", "25M", "25.3M", "25.6M", "25.9M", "26.2M", 
"26.5M", "26.8M", "27.1M", "27.4M", "27.8M", "28.1M", "28.4M", 
"28.8M", "29.1M", "29.5M", "29.8M", "30.2M", "30.5M", "30.9M", 
"31.3M", "31.6M", "32M", "32.4M", "32.8M", "33.1M", "33.5M", 
"34M", "34.4M", "34.8M", "35.2M", "35.6M", "36M", "36.4M", "36.9M", 
"37.3M", "37.8M", "38.2M", "38.7M", "39.1M", "39.6M", "40M", 
"40.5M", "41M", "41.5M", "42M", "42.5M", "43M", "43.5M", "44M", 
"44.5M", "45.1M", "45.6M", "46.2M", "46.7M", "47.3M", "47.8M", 
"48.4M", "49M", "49.5M", "50.1M", "50.7M", "52.3M", "53.8M", 
"55.4M", "57.1M", "58.8M", "60.5M", "62.3M", "64.2M", "66.1M", 
"68.1M", "70.1M", "72.2M", "74.4M", "76.6M", "78.9M", "81.3M", 
"83.7M", "86.2M", "88.8M", "91.4M", "94.2M", "97M", "99.9M", 
"103M", "106M", "109M", "112M", "116M", "119M", "123M", "126M", 
"130M", "134M", "138M", "142M", "146M", "151M", "155M", "162M", 
"171M", "182M", "196M", "210M", "226M", "243M", "259M", "274M", 
"287M", "298M", "308M", "317M", "327M", "337M", "347M", "358M", 
"369M", "380M", "413M", "450M", "490M", "533M", "579M", "628M", 
"679M", "734M", "795M", "861M", "934M", "1.02B", "1.1B", "1.2B", 
"1.31B", "1.43B", "1.66B", "1.98B", "2.21B", "2.3B", "2.48B", 
"2.61B", "2.79B", "3.02B", "3.1B", "3.16B", "3.43B", "3.7B", 
"3.76B", "3.94B", "3.92B", "3.81B", "3.8B", "4.07B", "4.11B", 
"4.13B", "4.23B", "4.07B", "3.79B", "3.58B", "3.9B", NA, NA, 
"2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", 
"2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", 
"2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", "2.08B", 
"2.1B", "2.12B", "2.13B", "2.15B", "2.17B", "2.19B", "2.2B", 
"2.22B", "2.24B", "2.26B", "2.28B", "2.3B", "2.32B", "2.33B", 
"2.35B"), dataset = c("GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", 
"GDP")), row.names = c(NA, -250L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: `grep("^[[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]+", x, ignore.case = TRUE)` will give all strings that start with one or more digits followed by at least one letter.

Comment: What other currency denotations? Try to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) that would better show what you're trying to do

Comment: I've added a screen shot of the dataset - I'm still learning how to create a reproducible example for this website.

Comment: If you already have the dataset imported into R, then `dput(head(my_data, n = 50))` will reproduce the top 50 rows (or whatever is sufficient for `n`).

Comment: To be clear, it is the **console output** _from_ `dput(head(GDPLong_df, n = 50))` that allows others reproduce the data structure, by copying that output into their environment as code.

Comment: @Greg, thanks so much. I was able to add the output.

Comment: My pleasure!  This here should give you a vector of all "currency denotation suffixes" that follow a whole or decimal number: `unique(gsub(pattern = "^\\d+(.\\d+)*", replacement = "", x = GDPLong_df$value))`; here `NA` appears in the results if an original `value` was `NA` to begin with.

Comment: @Greg, you're the best! It worked! Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help!  Shall I post it as an answer?  Mind you, it would need to be adjusted if there are any commas as a thousands separator (`"1,234"`) or as the decimal "point" (`"16,9M"`).

Comment: Also for conversion purposes, some countries do use the ["long scale"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion), in which "billion" refers to 10^12 rather than 10^9.

Comment: There are some options available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972571/changing-million-billion-abbreviations-into-actual-numbers-ie-5-12m-5-120-0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013217/convert-from-billion-to-million-and-vice-versa

Comment: @Greg, yes you can post it as an answer - it worked beautifully. Thanks again!

Comment: @hopefullyphdsoon Thanks, just posted it!

Answer (score 1):

By the [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216940/finding-letters-mixed-with-numbers#comment120604671_68216940) of [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16361325/hopefullyphdsoon), I am posting my [informal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216940/finding-letters-mixed-with-numbers#comment120565724_68216940) in answer to the specific question

> How do I find the other currency denotations?

From the `value` column in `GDPLong_df`, I simply remove the numeric (possibly decimal) "prefix", to leave the remaining text as the "suffix".

```
# Extract the denotation suffixes.
currency_denotations <- unique(gsub(pattern = "^\\d+(.\\d+)*", replacement = "",
                                    x = GDPLong_df$value))
# OPTIONALLY: Remove NAs if desired.
currency_denotations <- currency_denotations[!is.na(currency_denotations)]
```

Applied to OP's sample data, the output for `currency_denotations` gives us the denotations

```
"M" "B"
```

which excludes any `NA`s resulting from `value`s that were `NA` to begin with.

## Note

Further regex operations could be used to

- control for whitespace
- ensure the "suffix" is strictly alphabetical
- control for commas as thousands separators (`"1,234"`)
- control for commas as decimal "points" (`"16,9M"`)

but OP has already [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216940/finding-letters-mixed-with-numbers#comment120604671_68216940) the existing solution is sufficient for their needs.

## Warning

Caution should be used when [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013217/convert-from-billion-to-million-and-vice-versa) from terms like "billion" (and "trillion", etc.), as their magnitude differs according to the conventions used by various countries: namely the [long and short scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scale). For example, the former uses "billion" to describe `10^12`, whereas the latter uses it to describe `10^9`. However, I imagine that OP's dataset uses a standardized convention across the `value` column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to extract the alphanumeric suffixes and multiply their meaning by the number.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  mutate(mult_txt = value %>% str_extract("[a-z]|[A-Z]"),
         multiplier = case_when(
           mult_txt == "B" ~ 1E9,
           mult_txt == "M" ~ 1E6,
           TRUE ~ 1),
         value_adj = parse_number(value) * multiplier)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 250 x 7
   country year  value dataset mult_txt multiplier value_adj
   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 Aruba   1799  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
 2 Aruba   1800  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
 3 Aruba   1801  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
 4 Aruba   1802  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
 5 Aruba   1803  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
 6 Aruba   1804  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
 7 Aruba   1805  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
 8 Aruba   1806  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
 9 Aruba   1807  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
10 Aruba   1808  16.9M GDP     M           1000000  16900000
# … with 240 more rows
```

...and a test with more values:

```
options(scipen = 999) # so the output isn't shown in scientific notation
data.frame(value = c("16.9M", "900000", "192.0Z", "3B")) %>%
  mutate(mult_txt = value %>% str_extract("[a-z]|[A-Z]"),
         multiplier = case_when(
           mult_txt == "B" ~ 1E9,
           mult_txt == "M" ~ 1E6,
           TRUE ~ 1),
         value_adj = parse_number(value) * multiplier)

   value mult_txt multiplier  value_adj
1  16.9M        M    1000000   16900000
2 900000     <NA>          1     900000
3 192.0Z        Z          1        192
4     3B        B 1000000000 3000000000
```