# Is there a way to convert 1.00M to 1,000,000?

Tags: r, function

I've googled this a lot but I can't find any helpful functions based on my queries.

What i want is:

```
1.2K       ->  1,200
304.0M     ->  304,000,000
987.654B   ->  987,654,000,000
```

Is there any way that I can convert numbers with suffixes (K - Thousand, M - Million, B - Billion) to raw double numbers? I only found solutions to convert in the other direction.

Comment: Is the `dplyr` tag important ... ?

Comment: Here some examples the other way around which could be useful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159936/format-numbers-with-million-m-and-billion-b-suffixes) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340444/convert-numbers-to-si-prefix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string_vec <- c("1.2K", "304.0M", "987.654B", "1.78")

conv_df <- data.frame(
  symbol = c("", "K", "M", "B"),
  value = c(1, 1000, 1000000, 1000000000)
)

convert <- function(string_vec){
  
  data.frame(
    string_value = parse_number(string_vec),
    symbol = string_vec %>% str_sub(start = -1) %>% str_remove("[0-9]") 
  ) %>%
    left_join(conv_df, by = "symbol") %>%
    mutate(true_value = string_value * value) %>%
    pluck("true_value")
}

convert(string_vec)
```

Comment: since you're using tidyverse you could use `readr::parse_number(string_vec)` to get `string_value`

Comment: @Ben tnx nice to know it allows me to elegantly add 'no symbol'

Answer (score 1):

Something may already exist somewhere, but I was too lazy to check ...

```
suffs <- c(K=1e3, M=1e6, B=1e9)
conv <- function(x) {
    nc <- nchar(x)
    suff <- substr(x,nc,nc) ## select last char
    suffval <- suffs[suff]  ## find corresponding numeric value
    num <- as.numeric(substr(x,1,nc-1))  ## select all but last char
    num*suffval
}
conv(c("1.2K","304.0M","987.654B"))
```

This doesn't do any checking for bad suffixes, numbers without suffixes, etc. etc..